# How to set a background image for specific templates?

Tags: html, css, flask

How do I upload an image to be the background image for specific templates (i.e. the login page)?

If I put this in the `body {}` of the CSS file, it will change the background for all my templates. But I just want it only to show when the user is in the login page and signup page.

Answer (score 1):

Use classes for this. Set your CSS background image via `body.my-image-class { ... }` and then in the templates where you want that CSS to apply, add the class to your body tag: `<body class="my-image-class">`